# Counting outcomes of drawing two balls at a time

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

**Question**: A bag contains 4 black balls and 4 white balls. Suppose one draws two balls at a time, until the bag is empty. Count the number of outcomes where balls are pairwise the same color?

I am given the solution:

[image]

I don't get the multiplication of the two terms. Can someone help me understand the reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Me neither, it looks like it should be 6 to me. B B W W where B stands for 2 black balls, W for 2 white balls

${4\choose 2}=6$

B B W W, B W B W, B W W B, W B B W, W B W B, W W B B